# «Специально обученные люди» — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Раньше, если нужно было сделать то, что ты не можешь, приглашали специалиста. Сейчас — специально обученных людей.
По-моему, это звучит несколько унизительно — у меня возникает ассоциация с дрессированными животными.

Comment: Это  выражение  обычно  произносится  с  заметной  долей  иронии. Если  его  используют  в  этом  смысле,  то  -  правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так говорить можно - о работниках, набранных для выполнения несложной работы (иногда неприятной или опасной), требующей инструктажа или минимального обучения (газонокосильщики, кондукторы, такелажники). Если это в сфере услуг по дому, то работников могут обучить на радость заказчику так, чтобы они после работы убрали за собой скошенную траву, полили газон, а в дом заходили только в бахиллах, и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас часто можно услышать: придут специально обученные люди и всё сделают. Иногда это похоже на снобизм, но всё-таки обычно говорится в шутку.

Раньше было принято самим браться за мелкую   работу, выполнение которой  теперь мы все чаще поручаем различным службам, но при этом   не всегда считаем работников этих служб специалистами.

Специалист - ученый человек, получивший серьезные знания, навыки в какой-л. области.  И как человек ученый  он отличается от людей ОБученных и НАученных, которые имеют не глубокие, а ПОВЕРХНОСТНЫЕ знания, направленные на решение узкой (специальной) задачи.

А подтекст такой: я не считаю нужным уметь это делать и тратить свое время, чтобы научиться это делать.

Answer (score 2):

Это просто стёб, больше ничего. По-моему, ничего обидного, а тем более унизительного, в этом нет.