# Несколько удовольствий(?)

Tags: грамотная-речь

*За одну поездку вы получите несколько удовольствий* - имеется в виду, что за одну поездку, посетив несколько стран, вы получите несколько удовольствий. Разве можно так сказать?

Comment: Лариса! Сделайте доброе дело, удалите ранее ошибочно набранный в окне Ответ: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46591/Специально-обученные-люди-правильно-ли-так-говорить/420121#420121

Answer (score 3):

Лично я не вижу никаких причин отказывать слову "удовольствие" в праве иметь множественное число. Два удовольствия, три удовольствия, пять удовольствий - почему бы и нет? В данном контексте выглядит оправданным. Хотя строго литературно надо бы сказать ***"несколько раз получите удовольствие"***, но это уже жестокий пуризм, на уровне "граммарнаци".

Вообще вопрос интересный.
Есть некоторые существительные, которые не имеют множественного числа по разным причинам, среди них особой группой стоят названия чувств и состояний (гордость, терпение и т.п.) - но даже они периодически "бунтуют", требуя равноправия. Тут причина в том, что гордость или терпение - товар не штучный, можно иметь два *повода* для гордости, но гордость при этом останется одна. Но массовость использования "нескольких гордостей" показывает, что менталитет носителей языка протестует даже против такого, казалось бы естественного, ограничения.
А уж слово и понятие "удовольствие" настолько естественно вписывается в понятие о множественном числе... "Из многих удовольствий выбрал одно" - ну к чему тут придраться-то?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Это неграмотно.  За одну поездку вы получите удовольствие от посещения сразу нескольких стран.

Answer (score 0):

Неграмотно, и это мягко сказано. Гарантия получение фиксированного числа удовольствий — заведомо обман. А главное: удовольствие как явление абстрактное и субъективное в принципе индивидуально. «А кому — мать родна...» Помните? Разные, коренным образом отличные и противоположные зачастую, «удовольствия» не могут объединяться в кучки и пучки. Примитивная (от незнания языка) рекламная новация, безжалостная к языку: от *много удовольствия получил* через *массу удовольствий* дойдем до интервалов: *от двух до шести удовольствий*.

Посмотрите сюда, и оцените проделанное с *Россией*: [http://bezbukv.ru/inflect/россия](http://bezbukv.ru/inflect/%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)